# Taxonomy terms not mapping in D6>D7 migrate_d2d node migration

Tags: taxonomy-terms, migrations

I'm using migrate_d2d to migrate content from Drupal 6 to 7. I have a taxonomy term migration and a node migration. The taxonomy term migration runs correctly and creates 11 taxonomy terms, but when the node migration runs, the terms are not being mapped.

My migration code can be reviewed here: https://gist.github.com/vinmassaro/a7bce8175aa3cafffc2035092b0fe7be

It doesn't seem to be finding anything, because when I examine the output of of `$row` from `prepareRow`, there is no `[1]` element in the object coming from the source. What am I missing here?

[Migrate documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/1224042) says say the taxonomy terms are mapped this way, which is the format I have it in:

```
$this->addFieldMapping('field_taxonomy_reference', 'legacytermid')
     ->sourceMigration('LegacyTermMigration');
$this->addFieldMapping('field_taxonomy_reference:source_type')
     ->defaultValue('tid');
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not properly implementing the `prepareRow()` method, missing this part:

```
if (parent::prepareRow($row) === FALSE) {
  return FALSE;
}
```